# You must supply a resource ID for a TextView android error

Tags: android, arrays, resources, textview

I try all this day to resolve this error. I don't understand why my logcat prints:

```
05-06 21:45:59.559:
ERROR/ConversationList(9023): We have
chats... 05-06 21:45:59.609:
ERROR/ConversationList(9023):
UpdateList end... 05-06 21:45:59.839:
ERROR/ArrayAdapter(9023): You must
supply a resource ID for a TextView
05-06 21:45:59.839:
DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(9023): Shutting
down VM 05-06 21:45:59.839:
WARN/dalvikvm(9023): threadid=3:
thread exiting with uncaught exception
(group=0x4000fe70) 05-06 21:45:59.839:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023): Uncaught
handler: thread main exiting due to
uncaught exception 05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID
to be a TextView 05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:347)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1269)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1623)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:607)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:664)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1481)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.view.View.layout(View.java:6133)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.view.View.layout(View.java:6133)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.view.View.layout(View.java:6133)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.view.View.layout(View.java:6133)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.view.View.layout(View.java:6133)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:929)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1482)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method) 05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
Method) 05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023): Caused by:
java.lang.ClassCastException:
android.widget.LinearLayout 05-06
21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     at
android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:340)
05-06 21:45:59.879:
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9023):     ... 30
more
```

My Java file:

```
package fshizzle.com;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import cz.jabbim.android.data.JabberoidDbConnector;
import fshizzle.com.R;

public class ConversationList extends ListActivity {

//  private static final String TAG = "ConversationList.class";
    private static final int RESULT_CHAT = 4004;
    private static final int RESULT_DIRECTCHAT = 4005;

    private static final String TAG = "ConversationList";

    private ArrayList<String> chatList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private TextView tv;

    private String lastJid;
    BroadcastReceiver csr;
    IntentFilter f;

    boolean show = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.conversationlist);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contactList_NoConversation);

        csr =  new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                getChats();
                updateList(false);
            }
        };
        f = new IntentFilter();
        f.addAction("cz.jabbim.android.androidim.NEW_MESSAGE");

        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getChats();
        updateList(show);
        show = true;
        if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("startChat", false)) {
            startChat(getIntent().getStringExtra("jid"));
            show = false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        cancelNotification();

        registerReceiver(csr, f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(csr);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int pos, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(lv, v, pos, id);
        startChat(pos);     
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        new MenuInflater(getApplication()).inflate(R.menu.conversationlist_context, menu);
        AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Chat with " + getJid(acmi.position));

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuEnter:
            startChat(acmi.position);
            return true;
        case R.id.menuCloseChat:
            closeChat(acmi.position);
            return true;
        }


        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private int getChats() {
        final String[] returnColumns = {
                Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_ID,
                Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_CHAT,
                "MIN("+(Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_DATE)+") as 'firstReceived'",
               };

        SQLiteDatabase db = new JabberoidDbConnector(this).getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor result = db.query(Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION, 
                returnColumns, 
                null, //Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_FROM + "!= 'me'", 
                null, 
                Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_CHAT, 
                null, 
                "firstReceived ASC" );

        int count = result.getCount();

        chatList.clear();
        result.moveToFirst();
        while(!result.isAfterLast()) {
            chatList.add(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_CHAT)));
            //chatList.add("rafa@localhost.localdomain");
            result.moveToNext();
        }

        result.close();
        result = null;
        db.close();

        return count;
    }



        private void updateList(boolean startChat) {
        if(chatList.size() > 0) {

            if(chatList.size()==1 && startChat) {
                startChat(0);
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "We have chats...");
            tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            getListView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);





            ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this,
                    R.layout.conversation_item,
                    chatList
                );
            getListView().setAdapter(adapter);

            //startChat("rafa@localhost.localdomain");

        //  startChat(getIntent().getStringExtra("fromUser"));

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "We don't have chats...");
            getListView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv.setText(R.string.conversationList_noOpenConversation);
        }

        // close the database after usage
        Log.e(TAG, "UpdateList end...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==RESULT_CHAT) {

            int chats = getChats();

            if(chats==0) {
                finish();
            } else if(chats==1) {
                String jid;

                jid = getJid(0);

                if(lastJid.equals(jid)) {
                    finish();       
                } else {
                    show = false;
                }
            } else {
                show = false;
            }

        } else if (requestCode==RESULT_DIRECTCHAT) {
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void cancelNotification() {
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.cancel(Constants.NEW_MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION);
    }

    private void startChat(int pos) {
        String jid = getJid(pos);
        lastJid = jid;
        finishActivity(RESULT_CHAT);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Conversations.class);
        i.putExtra("jid", jid);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_CHAT);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }

    private void startChat(String jid) {
        finishActivity(RESULT_DIRECTCHAT);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Conversations.class);
        i.putExtra("jid", jid);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_DIRECTCHAT);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }

    private void closeChat(int pos) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = new JabberoidDbConnector(this).getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION,
                Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_CHAT + " = '" + getJid(pos) + "'",
                null);
        db.close();
        getChats();
        updateList(false);

    }

    private String getJid(int pos) {
        return chatList.get(pos);
    }

//  private void handleUpdateList() {

//  }

}
`
```

The error is here:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this,
        R.layout.conversation_item,
        chatList
);
getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
```

No error when I remove it.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this,
        R.layout.conversation_item,
        chatList
);
getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
```

What is the solution please?

`conversation_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

      android:id="@+id/conversation_item">

          <TextView 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/conversation_item_name" 
              android:text="Name Surname" 
              android:textColor="#ffffff" 
              android:textStyle="bold" 
              android:textSize="16dip" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_marginTop="10dip" 
              android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" 
              android:layout_marginLeft="10dip">
          </TextView>
          <TextView 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/conversation_item_date" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:text="17.6.2010 15:30">
          </TextView>
          <TextView 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:id="@+id/conversation_item_message" 
              android:text="Just some message..." 
              android:textColor="#ffffff">
          </TextView>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hmm.. This looks interesting. From the error it seems like you should provide TextView ID to ArrayAdapter constructor but documentation says `textViewResourceId; The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views`. Have you tried using TextView ID instead?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem lies in your `conversation_item` layout. The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) state that you must provide a resource with a **single** TextView. What does that layout look like?

As an example, this is what the simple_list_item_1 layout looks like, yours should be pretty similar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
/>
```

**EDIT:**

I just edited the question so your layout will show. Your layout is indeed wrong, you cannot have the linear layout there if you're using that constructor. You can use the other constructor ( `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)` ) and provide your custom layout and your TextView's id.

Comment: Presumably you want to use the textview "conversation_item" (I note, however, that you have two, so you will probably want to use a custom getView() method in the end). **new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.conversation_item, R.id.conversation_item, chatList)**

Comment: ok i try ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.conversation_item, R.id.conversation_item, chatList); but same error msg, i abandonned ...

Comment: Nobody are solution ? look the java file please and help me

Comment: Fixed by android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 has instead R.layout.conversation_item, hop !

Answer (score 33):

Had the same problem, needed to change the custom adapter from:

```
  ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            R.layout.conversation_item,
            chatList
        );
    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
```

to:

```
  ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            R.layout.conversation_item,
            R.id.sometextview_from_the_layout,
            chatList
        );
    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
```

I think the selected `TextView` will be used to generate the rowid, which may explain its need to be unique, but I'm not sure yet.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use a custom adapter whenever a Array Of Objects need to be listed in a Custom Layout View. Refer this simple and beautiful reference
[Populating a List View with a Custom Adapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter)

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you are using is for strictly a CheckedTextView. The problem arises due to you also providing a linear layout in your xml file. The most simple solution is to remove the linear layout and keep only the CheckedTextView. Cheers!