# Changing the text color

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a white background but with this layout i am blocked because text color is white too and i can't find a solution to make it red so i can set my white background, any help please (as u can see i am forced to use a red background her so i can see the white text).

```
public class QueueListActivity extends ListActivity {
// LIST OF ARRAY STRINGS WHICH WILL SERVE AS LIST ITEMS
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
String newtext;
String listFiles;
// DEFINING STRING ADAPTER WHICH WILL HANDLE DATA OF LISTVIEW
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

// RECORDING HOW MUCH TIMES BUTTON WAS CLICKED
int clickCounter = 0;

ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.queuelistactivity);
    Bundle extras1 = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    listFiles=GetFiles();

    StringTokenizer tokonizer1 = new StringTokenizer(listFiles,";");
    while(tokonizer1.hasMoreElements()){
        Log.i("verif","0");
        listItems.add(tokonizer1.nextToken());}
          initializeListItems();



    if (extras1 != null) {
        newtext = extras1.getString("newitem");
        listItems.add(newtext);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        getListView().setItemChecked(listItems.size() - 1, false);

    }




}



// METHOD WHICH WILL HANDLE DYNAMIC INSERTION
public void addItems(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(QueueListActivity.this, AjouterFiles.class);     
    QueueListActivity.this.startActivity(intent);


    /*
    listItems.add(userName);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    getListView().setItemChecked(listItems.size() - 1, false);*/


}

public void deleteItems(View v) {
    String toDelete = "";
    SparseBooleanArray sp = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();

    for (int i = 0; i < sp.size(); i++) {
        toDelete += ";" + sp.get(i);
        if (sp.get(i)) {
            listItems.remove(i);
        }

    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toDelete, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    initializeListItems();
}

private void initializeListItems() {
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setCacheColorHint(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(178, 34, 34));


    for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {
        lv.setItemChecked(i, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Best trick is you copy content layout file from `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` and make your own layout(my_list_view and edit the xml file and change the text color.

adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,my_list_view, listItems);

Edit save this file as my_list_view;

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" //white background
    android:textColor="#000000" //black color text
/>
```

Comment: how can i find android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice ?

Comment: you can just Ctrl+mousehover on android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice .. but i pasted that code see

Comment: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent').

Comment: Which sdk you are using ? Please try fill_parent

Comment: Agree with  @Dheeresh Singh give fill_parent instead of match_parent

Comment: yes it's fine now but in java code i have this
05-17 11:00:29.317: E/ArrayAdapter(987): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
05-17 11:00:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(987): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: @Rhaiem Hamza see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916459/you-must-supply-a-resource-id-for-a-textview-android-error i 'll get back to u in moment

Answer (score 7):

```
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set it in the XML layout:

```
<TextView 
 ...
 ...
 android:textColor="#FF0000" >
 </TextView>
```

Or programmatically:

```
textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
//textview must be defined in your class
```

Comment: if you can see i do not have a textview !!

Answer (score 0):

better to write custom adpter .

alternate but not good soltuon is use this layout xml inspace of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"


   android:textColor= Color.Red       //please correct the syntax
/>
```

This is  same  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice layout but your are now making same in your layouts with same ids to make the changes in it.

Comment: I make a new xml file and copy this into or what ?

Comment: make a new xml in layout with any of your name, paste this code in that xml and use this xml in place of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice in your adapter. As pre define ArrayAdapter will look for the id "text1" in get view and will get that as you have that also in your xml.

Comment: i have this now error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent').

Comment: Which sdk you are using ? Please try fill_parent

Answer (score 0):

you can try custom list view.. follow the link [click here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="11dp" 
/>
```