# Custom Spinner error : ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm currently developing my first android app, and i have faced a wierd porblem. well i'm trying to create a custom spinner with TextView and ImageView, the code apparently correct but when i click on the spinner to select item the app crushes ... i've tried many codes and ways but .. still the same issue, and when i've checked the Android monitor i find this error  **E/ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView**...

**CustomAdapter.java :**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

String[] spinnerTitles;
int[] spinnerImages;
String[] spinnerPopulation;
Context mContext;

public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, String[] titles, int[] images, String[] population) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_spinner_row);
    this.spinnerTitles = titles;
    this.spinnerImages = images;
    this.spinnerPopulation = population;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return spinnerTitles.length;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_row, parent, false);
        mViewHolder.mFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivFlag);
        mViewHolder.mName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        mViewHolder.mPopulation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPopulation);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    mViewHolder.mFlag.setImageResource(spinnerImages[position]);
    mViewHolder.mName.setText(spinnerTitles[position]);
    mViewHolder.mPopulation.setText(spinnerPopulation[position]);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    return super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView mFlag;
    TextView mName;
    TextView mPopulation;
}
```

**custom_spinner_row.xml**

```html
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/ivFlag"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="5dp"
  app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/tvPopulation"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
  android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivFlag"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivFlag"
  android:padding="5dp"
  android:text="TextView"
  android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/tvName"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivFlag"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivFlag"
  android:padding="5dp"
  android:text="TextView"
  android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:textStyle="italic" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] spinnerTitles;
String[] spinnerPopulation;
int[] spinnerImages;
private Spinner mSpinner;
boolean isUserInteracting;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mSpinner);
    spinnerTitles = new String[]{"Australia", "Brazil", "China", "France", "Germany", "India", "Ireland", "Italy", "Mexico", "Poland"};
    spinnerPopulation = new String[]{"24.13 Million", "207.7 Million", "1.379 Billion", "66.9 Million", "82.67 Million", "1.324 Billion", "4.773 Million", "60.6 Million", "127.5 Million", "37.95 Million"};
    spinnerImages = new int[]{R.mipmap.ic_launcher
            , R.mipmap.ic_launcher
            , R.mipmap.ic_launcher
            , R.mipmap.ic_launcher
            , R.mipmap.ic_launcher
            , R.mipmap.ic_launcher
            , R.mipmap.ic_launcher
            , R.mipmap.ic_launcher
            , R.mipmap.ic_launcher
            , R.mipmap.ic_launcher};
    CustomAdapter mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, spinnerTitles, spinnerImages, spinnerPopulation);
    mSpinner.setAdapter(mCustomAdapter);

    try{


    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (isUserInteracting) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, spinnerTitles[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView adapterView) {

        }
    });
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();
    isUserInteracting = true;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You must supply a resource ID for a TextView android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916459/you-must-supply-a-resource-id-for-a-textview-android-error)

Comment: i've seen this example but didn't understand what i have to change on my code .. can you please help me cuz i'm still new in android.

Comment: can you post your error log?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_row, parent, false);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivFlag);
            TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            TextView populationTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPopulation);
        imageView.setImageResource(spinnerImages[position]);
        nameTextView.setText(spinnerTitles[position]);
        populationTextView.setText(spinnerPopulation[position]);

        return view;
    }
```